# "Join" operator in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have two collections in my simple database in MongoDB : movies and actors. One entry in the movies collection looks like this:

```
MOVIES COLLECTION
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("id1"),
    "pre_mongified_id" : 19,
    "name" : "Borovo' Institut",
    "year" : 1984
    }
```

One entry in the actors collection looks like this:

```
ACTORS COLLECTION
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("actor1"),
    "pre_mongified_id" : 20,
    "first_name" : "asdf",
    "second_name" : "asdf"
    "roles" : [
    {
    "movie_id": ObjectId("id1"),
    "role": "Huseini"
    }
    ]
}
```

So my question is: How can i "join" the collections, so that I can get the info about the actors, with the names (name attribute) of the movies he plays in. So, instead of "movie_id" in "roles" array, I want to get the movie name?

Comment: You need 1) MongoDB 3.4 2) read some info about aggregation $lookup 3) try writing some code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You need to have mongodb version >= 3.2

```
db.MOVIES.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
            from: "ACTORS",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "roles.movie_id",
            as: "MOVIES_ACTOR_DETAILS"
        }
}])


db.ACTORS.aggregate([{
     {
        $unwind: "$roles"
     },

    $lookup: {
            from: "MOVIES",
            localField: "movie_id",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "ACTOR_MOVIES"
        }
}])
```

for more details please review [mongodb lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)